# How to unmask a password that have been masked by Elytrons mask command

Tags: wildfly, masking

I am using WildFly and are storing passwords in my `standalone.xml`. Lately I've begun to store our passwords in a credential store. The password used to access this credential store is masked using Elytron.bat's mask command. WildFly have no issue using this masked password but I also access the credential stores programatically, and here the masked password does not seem to work.

I've tried to use the `MaskedPassword` class and `PasswordFactory`. However the `MaskedPassword` class needs a variable called `initialKeyMaterial` which I do not know what is.

Here is the code I am using:

```
val passwordFactory = PasswordFactory.getInstance(MaskedPassword.ALGORITHM_MASKED_MD5_DES, new 
         WildFlyElytronPasswordProvider)

val rawPassword = MaskedPassword.createRaw(MaskedPassword.ALGORITHM_MASKED_MD5_DES, "keyMaterial".toCharArray, 25,
        "salt".toCharArray().map(_.toByte), "myPassword".toCharArray().map(_.toByte))

val unmaskedPassword = passwordFactory.translate(rawPassword)
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial key material is set by default to "somearbitrarycrazystringthatdoesnotmatter". You should be able to specify that and use a MaskedPassword

Comment: I should have specified. I have tried using that string, however it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

```
public class MaskPassword
{
    static final Provider ELYTRON_PROVIDER = new WildFlyElytronProvider();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String algorithm = "masked-MD5-DES";
        char[] keyMaterial = "somearbitrarycrazystringthatdoesnotmatter".toCharArray();
        byte[] salt = "12345678".getBytes();
        int iterationCount = 100;
        String clearPassword = "password1!";
        byte[] initializationVector = null;

        PasswordFactory passwordFactory = PasswordFactory.getInstance(algorithm, ELYTRON_PROVIDER);

        MaskedPasswordAlgorithmSpec maskedAlgorithmSpec = new MaskedPasswordAlgorithmSpec(
                keyMaterial, iterationCount, salt);
        EncryptablePasswordSpec encryptableSpec = new EncryptablePasswordSpec(
                clearPassword.toCharArray(), maskedAlgorithmSpec);

        MaskedPassword original = (MaskedPassword) passwordFactory
                .generatePassword(encryptableSpec);

        MaskedPasswordSpec maskedPasswordSpec = new MaskedPasswordSpec(keyMaterial, iterationCount,
                salt, original.getMaskedPasswordBytes());

        // Get the masked password as a string
        String maskedPassword = ByteIterator.ofBytes(maskedPasswordSpec.getMaskedPasswordBytes())
                .base64Encode().drainToString();
        System.out.println(String.format("Masked Password: " + maskedPassword));

        // Verify the masked password is the encryption of the clear password
        MaskedPassword restored = (MaskedPassword) passwordFactory
                .generatePassword(maskedPasswordSpec);
        System.out.println(String.format("Password Verified '%b'",
                passwordFactory.verify(restored, clearPassword.toCharArray())));

    }
}
```